# Code error in Android

Tags: android, compiler-errors

So this is one of my codes and whenever I click run my project fails to build because of the error in this code

```
android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview" />
```

for this code it says that there is unexpected end of file, beside the `>` in the code there is a small red zigzag line going across beside, `>` in the code. What should I do to fix the small code error?

Comment: Please post the contents of the XML file. The error indicates the XML is not well-formed.

Comment: This post is very vague, I would recommend reading the question guidelines.

Comment: looks like you're missing the starting '<'

Answer (score 1):

@Simran: 
I think you missing your Opening Tag Like `<` . Please add this .

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Hello,I am a TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I think you are new in Android .So before start please read its official documents for xml [Write the XML](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#write)

Comment: where am i suppese to put< in this, the last line is where the error is.                                                        <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview" />

Comment: ProcessNotCreatedException: Error launching emulator: Cannot run program "C:\Users\UmeshKhanna\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified how do i fixt this problem, and get the emulater to work again cause this pops up so how should i fix it?